# typescript guard in the method declaration

Tags: typescript

```ts
interface Initializing {
  progress: number;
}

var isInitializing = (x: any): x is Initializing => {
  return typeof x.progress === 'number';
}
```

The above code can be compiled without any error.

My question is related to ":x is Initializing" clause in the code. It seems that it doesn't affect generated JavaScript.

What ": x is Initializing" clause is used for? What kind of type checking is done? It seems that it is generating the same code when I call the function 'isInitializing' with any parameter. It produce the same JS code.

Examples are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [user defined type guard](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1007). It doesn't generate any code, but when the function is used with an if statement the compiler will automatically consider the passed in object to be the type specified in the `is` clause within the if statement.

Here's an example:

```
interface Initializing {
  progress: number;
}

var isInitializing = (x: any): x is Initializing => {
  return typeof x.progress === 'number';
}

var obj = { progress: 1 };

// obj is type "{ progress: number; }" here    

if (isInitializing(obj)) {
    obj; // obj is type "Initializing" within this if statement
}

// obj is type "{ progress: number; }" here
```